# include archivo de otro directorio

Tags: rutas

Tengo un problema con las direcciones absolutas.

Tengo un sofware multisitio. En un directorio padre tengo una carpeta "motor" donde están todos las funciones y en otras carpetas tengo los directorios de los distintos sitios web.

El problema está en que una función de la carpeta motor requiere un include al archivo de configuración que se encuentra en cada uno de los directorio de los sitios web

supongamos...

```
/srv/http/multisitio
/srv/http/multisitio/motor
/srv/http/multisitio/web01
```

El archivo desde donde estoy es est:

```
/srv/http/multisitio/motor/write/js/index.php
```

y el archivo que me solicita es este:

```
/srv/http/multisitio/web01/configuracion.php
```

Yo puedo subir así hasta la carpeta multisitio

```
require('../../../');
```

Pero cómo hago para que luego cargue la carpeta web01 donde está el archivo (configuracion.php) cuyas variables se necesitan, y es que el problema está en que el require no acepta una url para hacer la carga del archivo. Lo más difícil es que no se si haya alguna forma de hacelo automático para que funcione con cada carpeta de los distintos sitios. Tal vez definiendo una ruta... alguna idea??

Comment: por lo general se usa [`__DIR__`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php) para los `require` o `include` relativos independientemente de la carpeta donde estás

Comment: Intenta ```../../../web01/configuracion.php```, como mencionas estas en multisitio haciendo eso, ahora solo agrega la ruta a partir de multisito en adelante

Comment: Ok. ya entiendo entonces se puede agregar la ruta hacia adelante. Creo que podría funcionar, aunque no se si para los demás sitios (web02, web03). tal vez con uno que funcione sirve para los demás..